TextField causes initial microhang when tapped
I have a SwiftUI View containing a single text field element.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
            .padding()
    }
}

When I profile this code using the Hangs instrument I see a microhang of around 250ms the first time I tap into the text field to edit the text. Subsequent attempts to access and edit the text field do not cause any hangs.
I observe the same behaviour with the following two profile targets:

iPhone 15 Pro Max (simulator) with iOS 17.4 installed.
iPhone 13 (physical device) with iOS 17.4.1 installed.

I am not expecting any hangs. How can I avoid triggering such a hang?

Does this happen in Release or only in Debug?

It happens in both Release and Debug for both the physical and simulated devices listed above.
